# VB.net Iterate Anonymous Type Collection With Lambda Expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I attempting to iterate through an anonymous type collection but getting a
System.MissingMemberException
HResult=0x80131512
Message=Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ForEach' accepts this number of arguments.
and unable to determine why.  I am successful using For Each but unable to using a Lambda expression.

```
        Dim car As Object = {(New With {Key .Model = "Buick", .Color = "Blue"}),
    (New With {Key .Model = "Volvo", .Color = "Green"}),
    (New With {Key .Model = "Jeep", .Color = "Red"})}

    For Each item In car
        If item.Color = "Blue" Then Debug.Print(String.Format("{0} {1}", item.Model, item.Color))
    Next

    car.ForEach(Sub(x)
                    Debug.Print(String.Format("[0} {1}", x.model, x.color))
                End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

ForEach is a List(Of T) thing, not a LINQ thing..

```
    Dim cars = ({ New With {Key .Model = "Buick", .Color = "Blue"},
        New With {Key .Model = "Volvo", .Color = "Green"},
        New With {Key .Model = "Jeep", .Color = "Red"}
    }).ToList()
```

This creates cars as an array of anonymous and then uses ToList to make a list out of it; ForEach is then usable

Note: use plural for collections

Comment: Doesn't work ..   'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: @Malcolm, the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) for .NET Framework 4.8 and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) for .NET 5.0. As is always the case, you need to have referenced the appropriate assembly and imported the appropriate namespace in order to use it.

Comment: You have forgotten to  `Imports System.Linq` - arrays are enumerable and ToList is a linq extension of enumerable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me the right direction, here is a working example of what I was looking for.

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    
    Public Sub Main()
        
        Dim cars = ({ New With { .Model = "Buick", .Color = "Blue"},
        New With { .Model = "Volvo", .Color = "Green"},
        New With { .Model = "Jeep", .Color = "Red"}
    })

        cars.AsEnumerable.ToList().ForEach(sub(x) 
                console.WriteLine(string.format("Model: {0}  Color: {1}", x.Model, x.Color ))
            End Sub)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What is the point here? If you want a generic `List`, why not create a generic `List` in the first place? If you already have an array, why would you create a generic `List` from it just to use that `ForEach` method when you could just use a `For Each` loop to achieve the same thing? It seems like you see LINQ as a shiny new toy that you want to use everywhere, even when it's pointless to do so.

Comment: Also, what's the point of calling `AsEnumerable` in that scenario? The only reason to call that method is to get a reference of type `IEnumerable(Of T)` in order to disambiguate a method call. There is no other `ToList` method available on an array that you need to hide so calling `AsEnumerable` is pointless.

Comment: This is exactly the same code as I wrote, except that the ToList'ing is done a few nanoseconds later/cars remains an array

Comment: There is some merit to the point that ForEach should perhaps be avoided in preference to For Each especially thanks to VB's lambda syntax being a bit clunky. I personally find a For Each easier to read

Comment: By the way, if you're looking to try out new things, interpolated strings might tidy up the code a bit `Debug.Print($"The car is {item.Model} in color {item.Color} and costing {item.Price:0,000.00} in the sale finishing {DateTime.Today.AddDays(1):yyyy-MM-dd}")` as a quick demonof how to use them and how to format number/date etc (anything you would pass to a ToString goes after a colon)